# module.js:158 const cacheKey = JSON.stringify({request: request, paths: paths}); RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I installed mongoose and trying to create a new database in mongod using mongoose. I am getting following error while starting the nodejs server. can anyone suggest how to go along?

```
module.js:158
  const cacheKey = JSON.stringify({request: request, paths: paths});
                        ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Object.stringify (native)
    at Function.Module._findPath (module.js:158:25)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:467:25)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

my code looks something like this

```
module.exports = function () {

    var connectionString = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test';
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    mongoose.connect(connectionString);

    var userModel = require("./user/user.model.server")();

    var model = {
        userModel : userModel
    };

return model;

};
```